# How to handle errors in Reactive Spring webflux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

As there are many methods like `onErrorReturn`, `onErrorResume` etc, so which one's the right one to use in order to handle errors in Reactive Spring WebFlux for mono and flux?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Sharing my knowledge:

In total there are six methods provided to handle error, five discussed below:

- **onErrorReturn**: return fallback value for entire stream (mono/flux). E.g. if there’s a flux of 10 elements, and error happens on element 3, then rest 4,5,6… won’t be executed, instead the fallback value will be considered.
- **onErrorResume**: return fallback value in terms on Mono/Flux for entire stream (mono/flux). E.g. if there’s a flux of 10 elements, and error happens on element 3, then rest 4,5,6… won’t be executed, instead the fallback value will be considered.
- **onErrorContinue**: consumes (error,data) and does NOT split it over. It considers the consumer for the error elements, and leave the downstream chain as it for good elements. E.g. if there’s a flux of 10 elements, and error happens on element 3, then all elements (1 to 10) except 3 will have normal execution, but element 3 will have a different execution as mentioned in the consumer of onErrorContinue
- **doOnError**: consumes error and spills it over. Stops execution for further elements in stream.
- **onErrorMap**: cast one error into another.  Stops execution for further elements in stream.

**All these five methods come in 3 variants,**

- Simple: consider directly the expected argument
- With Exception: consider the expected argument, if the exception matches the exception class provided
- With Predicate: consider the expected argument, if the predicate yields true

Examples:

1. onErrorReturn: return fallback value

```
@Test
public void onErrorReturnDirectly_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorReturn(4)
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void onErrorReturnIfArithmeticException_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorReturn(ArithmeticException.class, 4)
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void onErrorReturnIfPredicatePasses_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorReturn(error -> error instanceof ArithmeticException, 4)
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}
```

2. onErrorResume: return fallback value in terms on Mono/Flux

```
@Test
public void onErrorResume_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.just(4))
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void onErrorResumeIfArithmeticException_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorResume(
            ArithmeticException.class,
            error -> Mono.just(4)
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void onErrorResumeIfPredicatePasses_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorResume(
            error -> error instanceof ArithmeticException,
            error -> Mono.just(4)
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}
```

3. onErrorContinue: consumes (error,data) and does NOT split it over.

```
@Test
public void onErrorContinue_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorContinue((error, obj) -> log.info("error:[{}], obj:[{}]", error, obj ))
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void onErrorContinueIfArithmeticException_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorContinue(
            ArithmeticException.class,
            (error, obj) -> log.info("error:[{}], obj:[{}]", error, obj )
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void onErrorContinueIfPredicatePasses_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorContinue(
            error -> error instanceof ArithmeticException,
            (error, obj) -> log.info("error:[{}], obj:[{}]", error, obj )
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}
```

4. doOnError: consumes error and spills it over

```
@Test
public void doOnError_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .doOnError(error -> log.info("caught error"))
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void doOnErrorIfArithmeticException_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .doOnError(
            ArithmeticException.class,
            error -> log.info("caught error")
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void doOnErrorIfPredicatePasses_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .doOnError(
            error -> error instanceof ArithmeticException,
            error -> log.info("caught error")
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}
```

5. onErrorMap: cast one error into another

```
@Test
public void OnErrorMap_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorMap(error -> new RuntimeException("SomeMathException"))
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void OnErrorMapIfArithmeticException_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorMap(
            ArithmeticException.class,
            error -> new RuntimeException("SomeMathException")
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}

@Test
public void OnErrorMapIfPredicatePasses_Mono() {
    Mono.just(2)
        .map(i -> i/0) // will produce ArithmeticException
        .onErrorMap(
            error -> error instanceof ArithmeticException,
            error -> new RuntimeException("SomeMathException")
        )
        .subscribe(num -> log.info("Number: {}", num ));
}
```

Comment: slight wording issue, `onErrorReturn` will return a fallback `value` while `onErrorResume` will return a fallback `Producer` could be a `Flux` or a `Mono` or any implemented `Producer`.

Comment: Be careful with onErrorContinue though, it can produce weird behavior when upstream flux is not resilient to error (see [apidoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) for details)