# How to catch timeout exception in Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

Currently I am writing a method that using WebClient to send POST request to another service.

```
  private Mono<GameEntity> callApplication(GameEntity gameEntity) throws URISyntaxException {
    WebClient client = WebClient.create();
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_OF_RETRY;++i) {
        String port = strategy.getNextInstancePort();
        URI uri = new URI(String.format("http://localhost:%s/game/add", port));
        try {
            Mono<GameEntity> response = client.post()
                    .uri(uri)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(Mono.just(gameEntity), GameEntity.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(GameEntity.class)
                    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
            return response;
        } catch (WebClientRequestException e) {
            //....
        } catch (Exception e) {
            strategy.incrErrorCount(port);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My approach is when the timeout occurs, we need to call another method `strategy.incrErrorCount(port)`. But the webclient does not throw any exception that can be caught in `catch (Exception e)` block.

Is there any solution to access this method when timeout occurs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle errors in Reactive Spring webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531829/how-to-handle-errors-in-reactive-spring-webflux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the timeout that happens due to

```
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
```

Then `timeout()` operator has another signature

```
public final Mono<T> timeout(Duration timeout, Mono<? extends T> fallback)
```

From java doc:

> Switch to a fallback Mono in case no item arrives within the given
> Duration. If the fallback Mono is null, signal a TimeoutException
> instead.

So, you can pass your `strategy.incrErrorCount(port)` into that method, so that line would look like this:

```
.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(3), Mono.fromSupplier(() -> strategy.incrErrorCount(port)))
```